# Ansible: How do I test/filter items in a list using a regex?

Tags: filter, ansible, conditional-statements

In an ansible playbook I want to loop a task over a set of usernames from one list only if the username or username followed by a suffix '.A' occurs in another list.

Sample playbook that fails:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - users1:
        - alice
        - alice.A
        - bob
        - santa
    - users2:
        - alice
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item }} realname {{ item | regex_replace('^([a-z]+)\\.[aA]$', '\\1') }}"
      loop: "{{ users1 }}"
      when:
        - "item | regex_replace('^([a-z]+)\\.[aA]$', '\\1') in users2"
```

This version skips `alice.A` while the `regex_replace` filter in the task itself returns `alice` as expected.

Actual output:

```
TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=alice) => {}

MSG:

Do something for alice realname alice
skipping: [localhost] => (item=alice.A)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bob)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=santa)
```

Desired output:

```
TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=alice) => {}

MSG:

Do something for alice realname alice
Do something for alice.A realname alice
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bob)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=santa)
```

Is it possible to apply a filter to the item to be tested?
If not is there a way to use something like `map()` to duplicate the entries in the `users2` list appending the '.A' suffix to each item?

When conditions I have tried that all fail:

```
    when: ("item in users2 | flatten(1)") or
      ("item|regex_search('\.A$')")

    when: 
      - "item | regex_replace('^([a-z]+\\.[a-z]+).[aA]$', '\\1') in users | flatten(1)"

    when: 
      - "item in users | flatten(1) | map('regex_replace','^([a-z]+\\.[a-z]+)$', '\\1.A')"

    when: 
      - "item | map('regex_replace','^([a-z]+\\.[a-z]+).[aA]$', '\\1') in users | flatten(1)"

    when: 
      - "item|map('upper') in users | flatten(1)"
```

The last one just to check whether the item tested was modified by the filter or not. (It is not AFAICT.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not needed. Use [*splitext*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) to get the *realname* and test its presence in the list *users2*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item }} realname {{ realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users1 }}"
      when: realname in users2
      vars:
        realname: "{{ item|splitext|first }}"
```

gives the expected results

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=alice) => 
  msg: Do something for alice realname alice.
ok: [localhost] => (item=alice.A) => 
  msg: Do something for alice.A realname alice.
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bob) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=santa)
```

---

You say you

> want to loop a task over a set of usernames from one list only if the username or username is followed by a suffix '.A'

The task above will accept any suffix not only '.A'. Test also the suffix to fix it. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item }} realname {{ realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users1 }}"
      when:
        - realname in users2
        - suffix == '.A'
      vars:
        arr: "{{ item|splitext|list }}"
        realname: "{{ arr.0 }}"
        suffix: "{{ arr.1|default('.A', true) }}"
```

See [Providing default values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values).

---

If you want to use *regex* change the variables below. This will give the same results.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item }} realname {{ realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users1 }}"
      when: realname in users2
      vars:
        realname: "{{ item|regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
        regex: '^(.*?)(\.A)*$'
        replace: '\1'
```

---

**Update**

Optionally, create the structure first and simplify the code in the tasks

```yaml
    users3_str: |
      {% for u in users1 %}
      {% set arr = u|splitext|list %}
      - name: {{ u }}
        realname: {{ arr.0 }}
        suffix: {{ arr.1|default('.A', true) }}
      {% endfor %}
    users3: "{{ users3_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  users3:
    - {name: alice, realname: alice, suffix: .A}
    - {name: alice.A, realname: alice, suffix: .A}
    - {name: bob, realname: bob, suffix: .A}
    - {name: santa, realname: santa, suffix: .A}
```

Then, the tasks below give the same results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item.name }} realname {{ item.realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users3|selectattr('realname', 'in', users2) }}"


    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item.name }} realname {{ item.realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users3|selectattr('realname', 'in', users2)|
                       selectattr('suffix', '==', '.A') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    users1:
      - alice
      - alice.A
      - bob
      - santa
    users2:
      - alice

    users3_str: |
      {% for u in users1 %}
      {% set arr = u|splitext|list %}
      - name: {{ u }}
        realname: {{ arr.0 }}
        suffix: {{ arr.1|default('.A', true) }}
      {% endfor %}
    users3: "{{ users3_str|from_yaml }}"
      
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: users3|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item.name }} realname {{ item.realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users3|selectattr('realname', 'in', users2) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Do something for {{ item.name }} realname {{ item.realname }}."
      loop: "{{ users3|selectattr('realname', 'in', users2)|
                       selectattr('suffix', '==', '.A') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, Never thought about using splitext this way! As the original problem is more complex I ended up using the regex part of the solution. But there too using the regex and replace vars makes the whole thing much more readable.
Too bad the ansible documentation is so scarce on details for all these filters. And the correct grammar/syntax as a whole.